# How to scale multiple QChartViews in a single window at once with rubberBand and force them fit this window

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've tried to create a window with some chartViews in it. Every chartView include 2 line-charts. My goal is to resize every chartView at once, by resizing only one of them with rubberBand. So, every chartView should listen for each other (event or so), and update their scale every time one of their neighbors is resized. I've tried to implement this idea (with 'simplex' listening for test, but needed 'multiplex' listening), but i didn't earn the success. Here is the code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6 import QtCharts, QtGui


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Charts")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.chart_view1 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view1)
        self.chart_view1.rubberBandChanged.connect(self.handle_rubber_band_change)

        self.chart_view2 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view2)

        self.chart_view3 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view3)

        self.chart_view4 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view4)

        self.chart_view5 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view5)

        self.chart_view6 = self.create_chart_view()
        layout.addWidget(self.chart_view6)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def handle_rubber_band_change(self, rubberband_rect):
        x_range = self.chart_view1.chart().axisX().range()
        y_range = self.chart_view1.chart().axisY().range()

        new_x_range = x_range.length() / self.chart_view1.rect().width() * rubberband_rect.width()
        new_y_range = y_range.length() / self.chart_view1.rect().height() * rubberband_rect.height()

        self.chart_view2.chart().axisX().setRange(x_range.center() - new_x_range / 2, x_range.center() + new_x_range / 2)
        self.chart_view2.chart().axisY().setRange(y_range.center() - new_y_range / 2, y_range.center() + new_y_range / 2)

    def create_chart_view(self):
        chart_view = QtCharts.QChartView()
        chart_view.setMinimumSize(200, 150)

        chart = QtCharts.QChart()

        series1 = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
        series1.setName("Chart 1")
        series1.append(0, 0)
        series1.append(1, 1)
        series1.append(2, 4)
        chart.addSeries(series1)

        series2 = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
        series2.setName("Chart 2")
        series2.append(0, 0)
        series2.append(1, 2)
        series2.append(2, 8)
        chart.addSeries(series2)

        # Axis setup
        axis_x = QtCharts.QValueAxis()
        axis_x.setLabelFormat("%.1f")
        axis_x.setTitleText("X")
        chart.addAxis(axis_x, Qt.AlignBottom)

        axis_y = QtCharts.QValueAxis()
        axis_y.setLabelFormat("%.1f")
        axis_y.setTitleText("Y")
        chart.addAxis(axis_y, Qt.AlignLeft)

        # Series connection
        series1.attachAxis(axis_x)
        series1.attachAxis(axis_y)

        series2.attachAxis(axis_x)
        series2.attachAxis(axis_y)

        chart_view.setChart(chart)

        chart_view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing) 
        chart_view.setRubberBand(
            QtCharts.QChartView.HorizontalRubberBand) 

        return chart_view


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

In addition, i'm trying to make the chartViews as compact as possible, to fit the window. My goal is this: [image]
But i have this. Too much blank space and unreadable values:
[image]
So, the point is to scale all charts at once with rubberband and force them fit the window together, with readable values.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour and outlook with PySide6 charts? Or it would be better to use some external libs?

P.S. For honor to not creating external question, is it possible to force charts to not becoming too small? I want them to zoomin endlessly, but, zoomout should be stopped when chart fits the size of the QChartView, so chart will not 'deattach' from the left and the right borders.

Comment: You should not use the ```rubberBandChanged``` signal. That signal is for selecting items with the ```setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)```. You should override the ```mouseReleaseEvent()```. Also you should access the range of the X axis like ```ax = self.chart().axes()[0]; print([ax.min(), ax.max()])```.